# jquery, calling one function within another passing parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, popup

I want to call one jquery function into another jquery function. The value from first function I need to pass into second function. The aim is that after the pop up gets open after selecting a radio button I want to trigger a window.open() function.

Here is What I am trying to do:

First jquery Function:

```
$("#myPopup").ready(function() {
  var popUpList = $(
    '<div><input type="radio" name="popup_w" value="1">1<br><input type="radio" name="popup_w" value="2">2<br><input type="radio" name="popup_w" value="3">3</div>'
  );

  $('#showPopUpButton').on('click',function() {
    popUpList.dialog();
  });
});
```

The "value" from above function which can be 1 or 2 or 3, I need to pass it to my below function and want to execute it.
Second Jquery Function:

```
$("#popup_w").change(function() {
alert(readCookie("test"));
if($(this).val() == 1)
  {
  var w="350px", h="450px";
  window.close();
  var webPage = window.open(window.location.href, "", "width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, left="+WINDOW_POPUP_LEFT+", top="+WINDOW_POPUP_TOP);
  createCookie("test", 1, 10);
  }
  else if($(this).val() == 2)
  {
    var w="50px", h="60px";
    window.close();
    var webPage = window.open(window.location.href, "", "width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, left="+WINDOW_POPUP_LEFT+", top="+WINDOW_POPUP_TOP);
    createCookie("test", 2, 10);
  }
});
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction. How can I pick value from first function and can transfer to second function and can execute it.

Both functions works proper individually. I want to link them.

Comment: do you need the "dynamic" value anywhere else than in `createCookie("test", 2, 10);` ?

Comment: The user will select an option and hence it will catch either 1 or 2 or 3. but I dont need dynamic value apart from createCookie(name, value, days) and readCookie(name) methods.

Comment: can't you do `createCookie("test", $(this).val(), 10)` ?

Comment: createCookie("test", $(this).val(), 10) worked but how can I call second function within first one. As value will pass from first function to another. Could you please advise on this.